# How to access "Sent Items" folder of another mailbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I am facing an issue with Outlook 2010 add in with VS 2010(C#). 
When user is sending mail with “Send As” permission the “Sent mail item” is getting save to user’s personal mailbox instead of send as’s mailbox sent item. 
Now I want to move it from user’s personal mailbox to send as’s mailbox sent items folder.
I was trying with this the following code

```
   Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application(); 
                Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");
                Outlook.Recipient oRecip = oNS.CreateRecipient(mailboxname); 
                oRecip.Resolve();
                if (oRecip.Resolved) 
                {  

                 Outlook.MAPIFolder sentItemssendas = oNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(oRecip, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);                       

                }
```

But this code is throwing an error “Could not complete the operation. One or more parameter values are not valid.” .
 But with the same code I can access olFolderInbox. After some search in Google I came to know “olFolderSentMail” is not having delegated access.
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._namespace.getshareddefaultfolder.aspx)
Now my question is there any way to achieve my functionality? How can I move sent mail from my personal mailbox sent item to “send as” mailbox sent item?

*Note :  As user is having only "Send As" permission so outlook only load user's current profile. Is there any otherway than Redemption?.